# kmz file not displayed in google earth plugin - have to zoom and dezoom to get it displayed

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin, kmz

I have to display large kml files into my website with the google earth plugin. The model seems to be always correctly downloaded but not displayed: sometimes i have to right click on the plugin like 5 or 6 times to see the model being displayed. 
after that it is corrctly displayed if i reload the page.

i'm using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
google.load("earth", "1");
var ge;
function init() {
    google.earth.createInstance('map3D', initCB, failureCB);
}

function initCB(instance) {
    ge = instance;
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
    ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW);

    google.earth.fetchKml(ge, "<?php echo $kmz ?>", function(kmlObject) {
        if (kmlObject)
            {
                var la = ge.createLookAt('');
                la.set(<?php echo $lat ?>, <?php echo $long ?>, <?php echo $alt+500 ?>, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 45, 10);
                ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);

                ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);


            }
    });


 }
     function failureCB(errorCode) {
        alert("failure");
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(init);  
</script>
```

i also tried to use createNetworkLink but the problem remains.
What should i change to get it work?

thanks!

Comment: When you say 'large kml files', what do you mean exactly? i.e. does the file contain a lot of mark-up? Or does it load a large model, large image, etc?  In either case can you post a link to an example of your kml?

Comment: my kmz files are approximately 4mB. they are composed of a large dae file (~2mB) and a large texture image (~2mB).
i uploaded a test file here: http://benoit.hanotte.free.fr/ge.html
When the plugin zooms for the 2nd time, the model should be displayed, but sometimes i have to zoom out to get it displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply the model taking time to load into the plug-in that is causing the problem. I have tested it in a number of browsers on a few OSs and the behaviour is the same in all cases.

The reason it works on subsequent page reloads is that the plug-in is caching the data so it isn't actually fetching the data a second time.

The zooming out, zooming in isn't doing anything to load the model any faster - it is simply passing the time until it loads.

On every test I have done the model always loads - but can take between 2 and 10 seconds to display...

There isn't a great deal you can do about this other than to try and optimise the .dae and image file within your KMZ archive to reduce the file size. This will make the model load and display faster than it currently does.

Comment: so you never had to zoom in and out to get it displayed? Because i had this problem even on my local server, where loading time is negligible, and i had to double right click twice to get it displayed.
i haven't find any callback method called on model display, only one called on loading completion, it would be very usefull to display a loading message.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have to zoom to get it to display. AFAIK a local server isn't going to reduce the 'loading time' only the 'downloading time' -no matter where the file comes from the plugin still has to load the model data... I too tested it using a local server set up. I believe there is an open feature request for some kind of 'loading completed' event in the api.

Comment: Yes here it is: http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=5  - it was the 5th request ever so maybe it will never be implemented :(

Comment: yes that would be greatly appreciated :(
anyway thanks for your help!